# iAd in sprite kit game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, iad, sprite-kit

I know there is at least one question asking how to integrate iAd into a sprite kit game, but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a portrait version of how to do it. There seem to be absolutely 0 tutorials online as to how to do this, so I came here. Can someone please tell me how to simply enable iAd in a Sprite Kit game? I have enabled `canDisplayBannerAds` and have used the `originalContentView` property for my UIView, but I keep getting a crash that says

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController originalContentView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a0a7410'**

any help would be appreciated, and here is my code in my view controller

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews 
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;
//skView.showsFPS = YES;
//skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Comment: it's working now. I wasn't linking the actual iAd framework to my application. I did that, and then i just imported iAd/iAd.h and now it works. Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Does this not distort or resize your scenes?

Comment: in a way, yes it does. If you want to know how to make it so it won't, go here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW2

Comment: What I done is I just dragged the iAd view onto the storyboard and do it the normal way. That puts the ad on all scenes, so I had to access the main scene from each other scene to change the main scenes userData or tag and the use a timer to check the the value every couple of seconds and then call a method to display or remove the ad.

Comment: My content is still distorted.  What did you do specifically in the iAd programming guide you linked to?  I'm pretty new to obj-c and iOS.

Comment: I did what you see above in the code. I have done some research though on the right ways of using iAd, and it seems that you should create an ADBannerView *bannerView; type variable, and in the init method, you should set the delegate to self. and then bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; then in the delegate methods, load the frame to being 44 or something like that. just check out the apple documentation and it will have code already given to you.

Comment: What do you mean by you were not "linking the actual iAd framework to my application"? I have the exact same code as you and am getting the exact same error. I imported iAD/iAD.h and am still getting the following error. -[ViewController originalContentView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14689c30

Comment: I'll put an answer up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those that don't understand, and those that are for future references, here is how I did this to my Sprite Kit game.

I had my game project created using the SpriteKit template in Xcode, then went to the project settings as so:

[image]

In the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, just make sure to hit the + button, and add the iAd framework.

After doing that, go to your view controller for your Sprite Kit game, and then type this:

```
// at the top 
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

// do this in .m, above @implementation
@interface YourViewControllerClassName () 
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *banner;
@end

// after the implementation line
// if you're needing to do it horizontally, do:
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.banner.delegate = self;
    [self.banner sizeToFit];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;
    SKScene *scene = [[YourScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [view presentScene:scene];
}
```

If you're doing the iAd in just a normal, portrait, you can do the above code, but you can also just use - (void) viewDidLoad instead...

Now is the delegate methods for the iAd to appear...

Go to the code above the @implementation line, and edit it

```
// do this in .m, above @implementation
@interface YourViewControllerClassName () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *banner;
@end
```

Now, go under the implementation line, and enter this:

```
// NOTE: THIS CODE CAME FROM APPLE MOSTLY
// I DID EDIT IT, BUT THE CREDIT GOES TO APPLE'S DOCUMENTATION
// ON IAD 
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if (banner.isBannerLoaded) {
       [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
       // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
       banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
    } 
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{
   if (!banner.isBannerLoaded) {
       [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
       // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
       banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

That is all that is required from the iAd to actually work in a SpriteKit game. I hope that I helped those that are going to read this.

Comment: Nicely explained step by step

Comment: thanks. I had searched for weeks on how to accomplish the task of using iAd in sprite kit. I made this for all those in the same boat i was in

Comment: Sorry for asking such question but, what should you do to put the ads on top of the screen instead of on the bottom?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's something that you would really want to do, but all you would have to do is instead of self.banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; you would say self.banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];and that should work for you. Don't apologize for the question though, everyone has their troubles with iAd..:)

Comment: In addition, I did have to add `[self.view addSubview:self.banner]` in the viewWIllLayoutSubviews method in order for the ad to actually display on my sprite kit scene.