# iAd banner to bottom of landscape screen in spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

I can not get the iAd banner to show up anywhere other than the top of the screen when i am trying to integrate it into my sprite kit game which is locked in landscape mode.
this is what i have in my view controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

_adview = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_adview.delegate = self;
[_adview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[self.view addSubview:_adview];
//[_adview setAlpha:0];

SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

// Create and configure the scene.
MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
scene.viewContoller = self;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to a similar question my help you out.

Also try initliazing the ad banner in viewWilllayoutSubviews, instead of viewDidLoad.

[How can I place a SpriteKit AdBanner at the Top of the View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414095/how-can-i-place-a-spritekit-adbanner-at-the-top-of-the-view/23465469#23465469)