# Implementing iAd in Sprite Kit with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, iad

I've been trying to figure out how to implement a portrait banner ad view at the bottom of my Sprite Kit game **with Swift** and am quite confused as to how to do it.

My references were the iAd Guide from Apple, which is unfortunately in Obj-C(I'm new to the whole programming scene so forgive my ignorance of Obj-C), as well as these:
[iAd in sprite kit game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669567/iad-in-sprite-kit-game)

[iAd in xcode 6 with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771295/iad-in-xcode-6-with-swift)

http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/

If anyone could suggest a method I would be really grateful to you, thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code with AutoLayout(code in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
    let bannerAd = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)
    bannerAd.delegate = self
    bannerAd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(bannerAd)
    let constraintsH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[bannerAd]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["bannerAd":bannerAd])
    let constraintsV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerAd(50)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["bannerAd":bannerAd])
    self.view.addConstraints(constraintsH)
    self.view.addConstraints(constraintsV)
```

Don't forget to implement delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, before looking at your solution, i added a line of code in my viewdidload which was: self.canDisplayBannerAds = true, and surprisingly when i tested my app an iAd banner showed up at the bottom of the screen where i wanted it to